# Angular 2+ Youtube Iframe API with existing iframe [src] binding failing to run events

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, iframe, youtube-api

I am having an issue with the youtube iframe API not running event callbacks on an existing iframe.

If I use:

```
<div id="player"></div>
```

It works

But if I use:

```
 <iframe id="player" [src]="mainVideo | sanitize"
 width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

It does not load any of the event callbacks like autoplay or alerting when the person has finished the video.

HTML

```
 <iframe id="player" [src]="mainVideo | sanitize"
 width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Typescript

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    const doc = (<any>window).document;
    let script = doc.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
    doc.body.appendChild(script);
    console.log(script);
}

ngOnInit() {
    (<any>window).onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = () => {
        console.log((<any>window).YT);
        this.player = new (<any>window).YT.Player('player',
            {
                events: {
                    'onReady': (e) => {
                        e.target.playVideo();
                    },
                    'onStateChange': (e) => {
                        if (e.data === 0) {
                            alert('done');
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

MainVideo

```
this.mainVideo = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" 
+ this.sect[0].mainVideoUrl + "?origin=http://localhost:56194&enablejsapi=1";
```

Can anyone help me understand why its ocurring?  The video itself plays when you click play, but it does not autoplay and it does not alert the user when the video is finished.

Thanks!

Comment: Did the `div` and the `iframe` exists in the same page with the same id?, have you checked whether there are errors in the console?, can you use jsfiddle for [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The autoplay wont work in Chrome and neither in mobile devices. Check some other questions and answers about why this happen.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave I either only used the div or the iframe.  One was commented out at a time. I want to use the iframe as I can bind the src to the different video ID's coming from my database.  Both of them had the id as 'player' but only one was uncommented at a time.

Also, autoplay does work in Chrome, but not for me when using the iframe method.  I can use the div and then have the ngOnInit player also provide the video ID and it works, its just that way sometimes doesn't get my server data right away and sometimes the Video ID doesn't end up working because of that.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave I've come to realize that it will work without the [src] binding...  If I don't use the binding and just add the link to normal src="linkhere" then it works just fine... However, with the [src] binding.. It will not work.

Comment: Still trying to figure out an alternative way when trying to dynamically load the video ID from a database since [src] binding won't work.